# To open the database+iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios

Always unable to open the database.
I am trying to insert the data.The data get inserted perfectly..
But when I am calling the method to get the data(Select Query) at that time the data base is unable to open.
I had never closed the database.
Is it compulsory to close the database each and every time.?

```
if(sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the full code,how can we point out your coding mistake?...So i guess you're not copying your db to documents directory.So here is sample code,use it as per your requirement.Happy coding :-)

```
-(void) viewdidload
{

    NSString *databaseName=@"xxx.sqlite";

    NSArray *documentPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *docsDir=[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    databasePath=[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];//Copy db to documents directory
    [self readFromDB];
}

-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase
{

     BOOL success;

// Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
// of the database and to copy it over if required
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

// If the database already exists then return without doing anything
if(success) return;

// If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

// Get the path to the database in the application package
NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

// Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];


}


-(void)readFromDB

{

sqlite3 *database;

if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *querySql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from xxx"];

    const char *sqlStatement=[querySql UTF8String];

    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array

        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)  {
           //get the data from db here                


        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }

    sqlite3_close(database);
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I found the solution is every time we have to close the database. And then try to open it

Comment: @shweta..if the above solution worked then please accept it as answer..thanks..happy coding :-)